# How to apply a function to the subarrays of a (m,n,n) numpy array without using a for-loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Starting with a `(m,n,n)` numpy array, lets say I want to apply some function to every `(n,n)` sub-array without using a for-loop.

The two functions I'd like to implement would be to first use `np.multiply` to element-wise multiply (not regular matrix multiplication) another `(n,n)` array with each `(n,n)` sub-array. Then I'd like to use `np.sum` to sum each resulting `(n,n)` sub-arrays to get an array of length `m` containing only those sums.

Is there a general way to apply a function to each sub-array without looping through the `m` index?

Comment: `np.sum(array, axis = (1, 2))` should do the trick

Comment: Okay thanks. The sum was just an example, I'm looking for a general way to apply a function to the sub-arrays. I'll have to do this with a few different functions besides `np.sum`

Comment: You need to specify the function. Is the function a numpy function or something you wrote? What is the equation of the function? eg. If I say the function is a numpy function, eg `np.sqrt`, `np.exp`, `np.cos` etc, then they are already vectorized for numpy arrays and you do not have to think of the subarrays but rather think of the array as a whole

Comment: Okay, I'll write a new question with the specific functions.

Comment: Specify the equation. Without the equation, we cannot vectorize the function.

Comment: Just edit this question. It has not been responded unto

Comment: If possible include an image with the equation.

Comment: It turns out that the functions aren't anything special, just numpy functions. I updated the question to include the main ones I need to do. Working on adding in specific code.

Comment: For multiply just use `array * another` which is for elementwise multiplication and for sum use `array.sum((1,2))` that should solve the problem

Comment: Notice that every function is unique on its own. You cann not have one method to apply all functions. Thats why we have the different vectorized functions. If there was just one method we would use the method instead of writing the different vectorized functions.

Comment: So if array a is `(m,n,n)` and array b is `(n,n)` just doing `a*b` would give me a new `(m,n,n)` where the sub arrays are the element-wise products?

Comment: sorry according to your example yes just do `a * b` and it should work. due to broadcasting

Comment: In the `python/numpy` context, "without a loop" actually means, "perform the loop(s) in compiled code".  Think of `numpy` methods as compiled building blocks, designed to work on whole arrays.  Many have some sort of 'axis' parameter.  And operators (and binary `ufunc`) use `broadcasting` to combine arrays with differing dimensions.  So each "function" has to be recast to make use of those tools.  Either that or use something like `cython` or `numba` to "compile" an iterative version.

Comment: If `m` is relatively small (and `n` large) the straight forward loop on `m` may actually be the fastest way. Under the covers, memory management for whole (m,n,n) arrays may be more complicated and time consuming.  What you want to avoid is many iterations on simple tasks.  There's no one rule to maximize performance in `numpy`.